# Notepad++ User Defined language for Perl

Tags: perl, notepad++

I'm trying to create my own language defined theme for Perl scripts so everything gets colorcoded the way I want.

The issue I'm having is that regexp sections are not getting colored the way I need them by using a delimiter in the UDL GUI.
Exmaple:

```
if($string =~ /^This is a string$/){
   print "worked!!!!!!\n";
}
```

I want "/^This is a string$/" colorcoded in red, but the delimiter I created takes the whole line after =~ /. How can I force Notepad++ to only colorcode until the last "/" on the line?

Here is my delimiter configuration. keep in mind that I already tried "/" instead of ((EOL)) and it didn't work. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Technically, `/` is the open and close delimiter. Unfortunately, it's also the division operator, which is what make this complicated. If you got into the habbit of using `m/.../` instead of `/.../`, you could set `m/` as the opening delimiter and `/` as the closing delimiter. That won't help for `s///`, though.

Comment: I used Notepad++ for a little while a good ten years back and I seem to remember the highlighter worked fairly well with Perl. I then switched to PSPad, which is also free and I found a lot better though, also with the highlighting.

Comment: You're going to have some trouble getting this to work. @ikegami is right about `m//` and `s///`, but then `m{}{}` and `s[][]` and `y!!!` and `tr@@@` are all valid (but `y///` and `tr///` aren't regex, just other quote-like operators). `m mfooom` is valid too. There's a saying that only Perl can parse Perl, and I would claim that the parsing engine that you've got with Notepad++ is not powerful enough to handle this challenge. If you want to learn more about parsing Perl, [this talk by Damian Conway](https://youtu.be/e1T7WbKox6s) from TPCiA 2017 about writing a single regex to parse it is good

Comment: When you're done watching Damian's talk, watch [these two follow-up lightning talks](https://youtu.be/EDQu0msc63E?t=1h9m4s) from the same conference as well. They are hilarious. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but PSPad is probably one of the uglies editor I have every seen :(. I like some of the tools it has and the syntax highliting for Perl is too simple. I guess I will keep using what I have in Notepad. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

I use this as one of my delimiters in my AWK definition:

```
Open:    ~/ (/ ,/ !~/
Escape:  \ \ \ \
Close:   / / / /
```

It isn't ideal, but it works well enough for me.

Comment: @JohnnyLoo You could do something similar for PERL. For example, Open: ~=/ Escape: \ and Close: /